# Error al insertar registros en php

Tags: php, html5

Intento almacenar valores en mi bd con php5 pero por alguna razón me arroja un error, he aquí el html y el php:
**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro.</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Registro.php" method="POST">
    Servidor:
    <select name="selServidor"> <!-- selServidor quiere decir seleccionar servidor-->
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Eur">Eur</option>
    </select><br>
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="txtNombre"><br>
    Clase:
    <select name="selClase">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select><br>
    Representantes:
    <input type="text" name="txtRepresentantes"><br>
    Descripción:<br>
    <input type="text" name="txtDescripcion"><br>
    Tipo:
    <select name="selTipo">
        <option value="Competitivo">Competitivo</option>
        <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
    </select><br>
    Contacto: <input type="text" name="txtContacto"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="btnRegistrar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paso</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php /*aquí se debe colocar los datos que se configuraron
durante la creación de la base de datos y la tabla
*/
    $server = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $contrasena = "";
    $bd = "LatinClub";//nombre de la base de datos

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contrasena, $bd) or die("Error en la conexion");

    $servidor = $_POST['selServidor'];
    $nombre = $_POST['txtNombre'];
    $clase = $_POST['selClase'];
    $representantes = $_POST['txtRepresentantes'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['txtDescripcion'];
    $tipo = $_POST['selTipo'];
    $contacto = $_POST['txtContacto'];

    $insertar = "INSERT into datosPC values('$servidor', '$nombre', '$clase', '$representantes', '$descripcion', '$tipo', '$contacto')";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar) or die('Error al insertar los registros');

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo "¡Datos insertados!";
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema sucede cuando en vez de decir datos insertados, dice error al insertar los registros

Comment: Que error obtienes al ejecutar el script?

Comment: Eso es lo que intento averiguar, se supone que si todo va como debe me debe mostrar datos insertados, en vez de eso me muestra error al insertar los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un error que veo es que en tu `$insert` no has añadido tus columnas a evaluar.

> Ejemplo actualizado:

```
$insertar = "INSERT into datosPC (servidor,nombre,clase,representantes,descripcion,tipo,contacto) VALUES ('$servidor', '$nombre', '$clase', '$representantes', '$descripcion', '$tipo', '$contacto')";
```

He puesto `servidor,nombre,clase,representantes,descripcion,tipo,contacto` como ejemplo, el nombre deberán de coincidir con tus columnas en tu tabla
datosPC

Comment: Lo probaré a ver cómo sale.

Comment: Listo, gracias, eso era lo que le hacia falta :D

Comment: También me funcionó. Muchas gracias